# How to draw rectangle canvas on camera with .Net MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I try draw a rectangle on camera View to center a card ID and return image cut. I done previously with Xamarin Forms with a Redenrers to IOS and Android, but libraries already deprecated or obsolete.

I want help to another method or package to resolve it. I search some days, but I haven't found a solution.

P.D. I don't need recognize card ID info, only need crop image.

Comment: I don't know the detail of your requirement, but [Hander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0) in Maui is equivalent to [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Some Forums inform us about "Absolute Layout". You can add CameraView and Rect() to Absolute Layout as Children. I can't make it work neither, but many people do that with this way.